Two affine varieties are birational iff their projective closure are isomorphic?
Let $X, Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be two (irreducible) affine varieties over some algebraically closed field $k$. If their closures are isomorphic, then I believe they are birational. But is it necessary for $\bar{X}, \bar{Y}$ to be isomorphic in order that $X, Y$ are birational?
I am only a beginner in AG. I ask this problem because: i) it seems intuitive that birational affine varieties differ by only a 'small' part (a closed set, I guess); ii) for all examples of affine birational varieties $X, Y$ I have come across, it happens that $k[X], k[Y]$ are rings of fractions of the same affine ring.
If this is not correct, can anyone offer me a counterexample?

The linked duplicate shows an instance where $X\cong Y$ and therefore they're trivially birational, but $\overline{X}\not\cong\overline{Y}$.
